# Merge 2 table with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a task to insert all table into next one info with condition. I need to merge the same value like `Abonentas` table primary key `(AbonentoID)`, And where `miestoID` is 1. I've tried function merge but I've gotten an error after the `Inner Join`. I've searched a lot of info about it and I can't find the solution.

#### Error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'

#### Code

```
MERGE dbo.VipAbonentai vip 
USING (SELECT ab.abonentoID From Abonentas as ab
Inner join Asmuo as A on ab.asmensID = A.asmensID
Inner join Miestas as M on M.miestoID = M.miestoID
Where M.miestoID = 1)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET 
    vip.abonentoID = ab.abonentoID,
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
THEN
INSERT (AbonentoID, asmensID, planoID, numeris, sutartiesPradzia, 
sutartiesPabaiga)
VALUES (ab.AbonentoID, ab.asmensID, ab.planoID, ab.numeris, 
ab.sutartiesPradzia, ab.SutartiesPabaiga) ;
```

Comment: You need join criteria between your derived table and the when matched clause.

Comment: can you explain me more?

Comment: `merge into <table> using <your derived table> ON <join criteria> when matched...`  You have to join your derived table to `dbo.VipAbonentai`. Here's a [link to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I wouldn't use MERGE for an update. Just use an update statement.

Comment: Also, you are referencing the alias "ab" but that doesn't exist in your query. And many other syntax errors.

Comment: Oh sorry  i miss some mistakes, but same problem exist

Comment: I would still not use MERGE even for an upsert like this. There have been many issues with MERGE. This article is a bit old but many of these issues still have not been fixed or marked as "by design" or "won't fix".  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: @Andrew at the time of my first comment the code was not doing an upsert.

Comment: @aduguid Yes, thank you

Comment: no worries, mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here's how I'd write the merge.

The following columns need to be returned in the `VipAbonentai_source`. I'm not sure about which tables they are coming from. I've written the statement as a [common table expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
  ab.[abonentoID]
, [asmensID]
, [planoID]
, [numeris]
, [sutartiesPradzia]
, [sutartiesPabaiga]
```

If you wrap it in a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you can run it on a [rollback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) without effecting any records. Also, I output the records to see what will change. If you have triggers on the table, you'll have to comment out the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) line.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

WITH 
VipAbonentai_source
AS 
(
    SELECT 
         ab.[abonentoID]
       , [asmensID]
       , [planoID]
       , [numeris]
       , [sutartiesPradzia]
       , [sutartiesPabaiga]
    FROM 
      Abonentas AS ab
      INNER JOIN Asmuo AS A ON ab.[asmensID] = A.[asmensID]
      INNER JOIN Miestas AS M ON M.[miestoID] = M.[miestoID]
    WHERE 
      M.[miestoID] = 1
) 
MERGE dbo.VipAbonentai AS T
USING VipAbonentai_source AS S
ON T.[abonentoID] = S.[abonentoID]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT
(
  [abonentoID], [asmensID], [planoID], [numeris], [sutartiesPradzia], [sutartiesPabaiga]
)
VALUES
(
  S.[abonentoID], S.[asmensID], S.[planoID], S.[numeris], S.[sutartiesPradzia], S.[sutartiesPabaiga]
)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET
 T.[asmensID] = S.[asmensID]
, T.[planoID] = S.[planoID]
, T.[numeris] = S.[numeris]
, T.[sutartiesPradzia] = S.[sutartiesPradzia]
, T.[sutartiesPabaiga] = S.[sutartiesPabaiga]
--WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE --< You may want to add a WHERE clause here
--THEN DELETE
OUTPUT @@SERVERNAME AS [Server Name], DB_NAME() AS [Database Name], $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
--COMMIT TRANSACTION;

GO
```